# Have any SHA-1 collisions happened?

Tags: collision-resistance, sha-1

No SHA-1 collisions are actually known, though there are a number of cryptographic attacks to weaken it.

But, how likely is it that, of all the SHA-1 hashes computed since the invention of the algorithm, there has been a collision?

Not sure how to approach this, but it probably involves the Birthday Problem?

(if there's a better SE to ask this in, let me know)

Comment: Besides [the Q&A linked above](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29754/what-is-the-complexity-of-finding-sha-1-collisions), also note **[this answer to “SHA-1 collisions - what about practical attacks?”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20661/12164)**

Answer (score 3):

In order for a collision to happen "by chance", about $2^{80}$ hashes need to have been computed. If 1000 hashes were computed every millisecond, then this would take 38,334,786,263 years. So, I doubt that this has happened by chance.

Having said that, I would be very surprised if large government organizations do not already have SHA collisions (using better collision finding algorithms).